# Java Geolocation calculation - not getting the right values

Tags: java, javafx, geolocation, maps

I have Javafx application for a flightmanagement system and I have to calculate the distance between Airports for example from Dusseldorf International to Koln Airport, I tried Geodys api found from a post here but it did not give me the values I needed. Can someone give me a pointer for this problem? I have the Latitude and Longitude given from my Database.

this is the Api code:

```
public double distanceCalculator() throws SQLException {

        Statement disanceState = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet startFlughafen = disanceState
                .executeQuery("select * from flughaefen where name  =\"" + startAirport.getValue() + "\"");
        while (startFlughafen.next()) {
            longitudeStart = startFlughafen.getDouble("lon");
            latidudeStart = startFlughafen.getDouble("lat");

        }
        ResultSet zielFlughafen = disanceState
                .executeQuery("select * from flughaefen where name  =\"" + targetAirport.getValue() + "\"");
        while (zielFlughafen.next()) {
            longitudeZiel = zielFlughafen.getDouble("lon");
            latidudeZiel = zielFlughafen.getDouble("lat");

        }

        GeodeticCalculator geoCalc = new GeodeticCalculator();

        Ellipsoid reference = Ellipsoid.WGS84;

        GlobalPosition startFlughafenValues = new GlobalPosition(latidudeStart, longitudeStart, 0.0); // Point A

        GlobalPosition zielFlughafenValues = new GlobalPosition(latidudeZiel, longitudeZiel, 0.0); // Point B

        distanceSet = geoCalc.calculateGeodeticCurve(reference, startFlughafenValues, zielFlughafenValues)
                .getEllipsoidalDistance(); // Distance between Point A and Point B

        return distanceSet;
    }
```

This is another formular what I have tried:

```
public double distanceCalculator() throws SQLException {    

        Statement disanceState = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet startFlughafen = disanceState
                .executeQuery("select * from flughaefen where name  =\"" + startAirport.getValue() + "\"");
        while (startFlughafen.next()) {
             longitudeStart = startFlughafen.getDouble("lon");
             latidudeStart = startFlughafen.getDouble("lat");

        }
        ResultSet zielFlughafen = disanceState
                .executeQuery("select * from flughaefen where name  =\"" + targetAirport.getValue() + "\"");
        while (zielFlughafen.next()) {
             longitudeZiel = zielFlughafen.getDouble("lon");
             latidudeZiel = zielFlughafen.getDouble("lat");

        }


        final int R = 6371; // Radius of the earth

        double latDistance = Math.toRadians(latidudeZiel - latidudeStart);
        double lonDistance = Math.toRadians(longitudeZiel - longitudeStart);
        double a = Math.sin(latDistance / 2) * Math.sin(latDistance / 2)
                + Math.cos(Math.toRadians(longitudeStart)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(longitudeZiel))
                * Math.sin(lonDistance / 2) * Math.sin(lonDistance / 2);
        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));
         distances = R * c ; // convert to meters

         distances = Math.pow(distances, 2) ;

         return Math.sqrt(distances);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several libraries which could do that but under the hood they also often use the GeographicLib: https://geographiclib.sourceforge.io/ A link to the Java version can be found in the text. The class in there you are probably looking for is called Geodesic.